# Como controlar rotas usando middleware do laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, auth, middleware

Tenho um sistema com as seguintes rotas

1. '\'
2. '\despesas'
3. '\register'
4. '\login'
5. '\home'

dessas rotas gostaria de deixar apenas disponíveis para usuário NÃO autenticados '\' e '\login',

para isso alterei a função handle da classe RedirectIfAuthenticated, para que quando ele estiver autenticado seja direcionado para home, caso contrário vá para pagina de login. Isso funcionou para register, mas quando acesso \despesas consigo acessar mesmo não estando autenticado.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (!$request->is('login') && Auth::guard($guard)) {
        return redirect('/home');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode chegar no seu middleware se o usuário está logado:

```
/**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        if (!Auth::check()) {
            return redirect('/login');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

E no seu arquivo de rotas agrupar as rotas que desejam que sejam autenticadas dentro desse Middleware:

```
 Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth_site'], function () {
    Route::get('despesas', ['uses' => 'DespesasController@index', 'as' => 'despesas']);
   [...]
 });
```

Comment: Será q não posso fazer o caminho oposto? agrupar as rotas não quero que autentique, caso contrário autenticar as outras, ou tenho q espetrificar apenas as rotas que precisem de autenticação?

Comment: Pode também, aí é só fazer a condição oposta do que coloquei no middleware na resposta acima, ai cria como guest e agrupa essas rotas nesse Middleware